# Haskell split list

Tags: haskell

I would like to separate this list, in a list of lists in which to separate whenever you see a different character, example:

- `["222", "2333"]` → `[["222"], ["2"], ["333"]]`

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why `[["222"], ["2"], ["333"]]` instead of `["222", "2", "333"]`?

Comment: You may do like `myFunc = (group =<<)`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this for a single string with `group` from `Data.List`:

```
group "2333" == ["2","333"]
```

You can do an action for each element in a list with `map`:

```
map group ["222","2333"] === [["222"],["2","333"]]
```

You can flatten a list of lists with `concat`:

```
(concat $ map group ["222","2333"]) == ["222","2","333"]
```

And there's a `concatMap` to do both at once:

```
concatMap group ["222","2333"] == ["222","2","333"]
```